# How to add a cube in the center of the screen, and so that it never leaves?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

Good afternoon!
I'm new to SceneKit. And I can not solve this problem.

I need to get the cube has always been in the center of the screen and followed the camera until it finds a horizontal and stand on it.
And I have it stays in one place
Here is my simple code right now.

```
        import UIKit
        import SceneKit
        import ARKit

        class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

            @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()


                let scene = SCNScene()


                let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0)


                let material = SCNMaterial()

                material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
                material.specular.contents = UIColor(white: 0.6, alpha: 1.0)



                let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
                boxNode.geometry?.materials = [material]


                boxNode.position = SCNVector3(0,0,-1.0)


                scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

                sceneView.scene = scene


                //------------------------------------
                // Set the view's delegate
                sceneView.delegate = self

                // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
                sceneView.showsStatistics = true


                // Set the scene to the view
                sceneView.scene = scene
            }

            override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewWillAppear(animated)

                // Create a session configuration
                let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

                // Run the view's session
                sceneView.session.run(configuration)
            }

            override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

                // Pause the view's session
                sceneView.session.pause()
            }

       }
```

Help me please. Do not swear)

Comment: Egor, could you be a little more specific, I'm not clear on what you mean? Are you using the default scenekit camara?

Comment: Voltan, I want this cube to follow the camera, and not stay in one place

Comment: Voltan, Yes, you’re right. I need it. But how to implement this with this code? help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an update to your code that ensure's the box is always at the center of the screen. Once the code detects a plane, it set's the box's parent as the plane anchor.

This is all very primitive, but should help you. If you want the node to float in the center of the screen, uncomment the `SCNTransaction`s within the `willRenderScene` callback. If you want the box to always face the user, you can add a `lookAtConstraint`

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    var boxNode: SCNNode? // keep a reference to the cube

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let scene = SCNScene()


        let boxNode = createBox()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
        self.boxNode = boxNode

        sceneView.scene = scene


        //------------------------------------
        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self

        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true


        // Set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene
    }

    func createBox() -> SCNNode {
        let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0)

        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
        material.specular.contents = UIColor(white: 0.6, alpha: 1.0)

        let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
        boxNode.geometry?.materials = [material]

        return boxNode;
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }

    // on willRender update the cube's position.
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {
        // get camera translation and rotation
        guard let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView else { return }
        let transform = pointOfView.transform // transformation matrix
        let orientation = SCNVector3(-transform.m31, -transform.m32, -transform.m33) // camera rotation
        let location = SCNVector3(transform.m41, transform.m42, transform.m43) // camera translation

        let currentPostionOfCamera = orientation + location
//        SCNTransaction.begin()
        if let boxNode = self.boxNode {
            boxNode.position = currentPostionOfCamera
        }
//        SCNTransaction.commit()
    }


    // detect plances
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        guard anchor is ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
        if let boxNode = self.boxNode {
            let newBoxNode = createBox() // create a new node for the center of the screen
            self.boxNode = newBoxNode
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            boxNode.removeFromParentNode()
            node.addChildNode(boxNode) // set the current box to the plane.
            sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(newBoxNode) // add the new box node to the scene
            SCNTransaction.commit()
        }

    }
}

extension SCNVector3 {
    static func + (left: SCNVector3, right: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3Make(left.x + right.x, left.y + right.y, left.z + right.z)
    }
}
```